# Question regarding numbers on chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, coloring

On one square of a 5×5 chessboard, we write -1 and on the other 24 squares +1. In one move, you may reverse the signs of one a×a subsquare with a>1. My goal is to reach +1 on each square. On which squares should -1 be to reach the goal?

Please help me with this problem. I am not able to understand ´how to approach such a problem

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use $0$ instead of $+1$, and $1$ instead of $-1$. Write the state of the board as a vector of 25 elements (reading left-to-right, top to bottom), each of which you should think of as a binary bit.

Now each possible "move" is also a 25-vector, with $1$s in the squares that get "flipped". To apply a "move", you add the move-vector to the starting vector. Your goal is to get a vector of all zeroes. So the question becomes:

Given the $16 + 9 + 4 + 1$ move vectors, let $S$ be their span (over the integers mod 2). Which vectors containing exactly one "1" are in this span?

That's a straightforward (although tedious) computation. You also don't need the four "size four block" vectors, because they're in the span of the size-two block vectors.

Comment: So where is the answer?

Comment: @WhatsUp We are very much allowed to give partial answers and hints on this site. Giving a systematic approach to finding a solution (even without explicitly applying said approach and actually solve the problem) definitely qualifies as a valid answer post.

Comment: @WhatsUp: You might have noticed that the first word of my answer was "Hint". If that offends you, by all means downvote.

Comment: @Arthur Of course, I know this is a valid answer. I just want to know the answer to the question without computing the $25$-dimensional vectors myself.

Comment: @JohnHughes No no, I'm by no means offended. You may simply say "I don't have the answer to the question" and I'm OK.

Comment: I *do* have the answer; I'm just not disclosing it, and I'm doing that on purpose, because the teacher in me wants OP to have the experience of seeing how something like this works out.

Comment: @JohnHughes But did you get your answer via the method you stated in your post, i.e. doing calculation with $25$ dimensional vectors? I would have used some computer algebra system to do that, but how did you managed to get the answer and write down your post just $10$ minutes after the question is posted?

Comment: Dear Teacher in @JohnHughes, I would very much like to see the detailed steps of your $25$-dimensional calculations. Could you please share them with me? It is very impressive that you did it so quickly, so I definitely want to learn your technique.

Comment: @Whatsup: I already had matlab code lying around from having solved "lights out"-style puzzles.

Comment: @JohnHughes So the teacher in you hides your usage of matlab from the OP and wants him to do the $25$-dimensional calculations by hand, "to have the experience of seeing how something like this works out"?

Comment: I never said "by hand", and I think that actually looking at the 25 x 30 matrix (or a few rows of it) is instructive, as is realizing you can row-reduce mod 2, etc.  I might also have known the answer from having worked it out previously by hand. Knowing an answer instantly doesn't imply that I **learned** it instantly. I did, after all, mention that the calculation was tedious, which doesn't suggest you can do it in 10 minutes. But please, **go ahead and downvote my hint**  because it doesn't meet your standards for unstated claims.

Comment: BTW, I'd love to know an easy way to see the answer, but it's not coming to me, even *knowing* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer, although it's hard to imagine exactly how someone who hadn't seen it before would come up with it.

Let
$$
A = \pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
},
B = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
},
C =
\pmatrix{
0&     1  &   1&     0 &    1\\
     1&     0 &    0 &    1  &   0\\
     1&    0 &    0  &   1  &   0\\
     0&     1&     1 &    0 &    1\\
     1&     0&     0 &    1 &    0
}
.
$$
Define the dot product of two matrices to be the sum of all products of corresponding entries (mod 2).

Then the dot products of any 2x2 block of 1s with $A,B, C$ are all zero; the same goes for any dot product of any 3x3 blocks of 1s with $A,B,C$; the same goes for
the dot product of the $5x5$ matrix of all 1s. (And 4x4s as well, but that's a consequence of 2x2s).

Thus any matrix in the span of these block matrices ALSO has zero dot-product with $A$, $B$, and $C$. But if we look at a matrix with a single 1 in the upper left corner, its dot product with $B$ is $1$...so it can't be in the span. The same argument works for every single-1 matrix except one. Look for the common "0" in A,B,C.

How'd I figure this out? I looked for a rational kernel-basis for the matrix I described in the previous answer, and then fiddled a bit mod 2. I'd already worked out matrix $A$ without that, but $B$ would have taken longer to come up with, and $C$ is just...weird. So as I said, although this is a quick-and-dirty argument, I don't see how a contest-math person would come up with it.

Comment: A simplification: With the idea of invariance, matrix B is quite easy to come up by looking at the rules (esp if you suspect that only the center square works). Then via matrix B and $B^T$, we see that the only possibility is the center square.

Comment: Right...good point. I was fixated on wanting all 3 matrices. I actually generated $B^t$ by looking at $B + A$, but decided "what use is THAT? It's still int he same span..." :(